# How do you "properly" implement Dispose() (according to FxCop) when your implementation is an empty method? (CA1063)

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, fxcop

I have an implementation of an interface, and that interface extends `IDisposable`. In my particular implementation of the interface, I don't need to dispose anything, so I just have an empty `Dispose()` method.

```
public interface IMyStuff : IDisposable
{
}

public MyStuffImpl : IMyStuff
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Now in FxCop, this results in a CA1063:

```
Error, Certainty 95, for ImplementIDisposableCorrectly
{
    Resolution   : "Provide an overridable implementation of Dispose(
                   bool) on 'MyStuffImpl' or mark the type as sealed. 
                   A call to Dispose(false) should only clean up native 
                   resources. A call to Dispose(true) should clean up 
                   both managed and native resources."
}
CriticalWarning, Certainty 75, for CallGCSuppressFinalizeCorrectly
{
    Resolution   : "Change 'MyStuffImpl.Dispose()' to call 'GC.SuppressFinalize(
                   object)'. This will prevent derived types that introduce 
                   a finalizer from needing to re-implement 'IDisposable' 
                   to call it."
}
Error, Certainty 95, for ImplementIDisposableCorrectly
{
    Resolution   : "Modify 'MyStuffImpl.Dispose()' so that it 
                   calls Dispose(true), then calls GC.SuppressFinalize 
                   on the current object instance ('this' or 'Me' in Visual 
                   Basic), and then returns."
}
```

So, it looks like I can resolve this in one of 2 ways:

---

Make the class `sealed`:

```
public sealed MyStuffImpl : IMyStuff
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

---

Implement part of the typical pattern:

```
public MyStuffImpl : IMyStuff
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
    }
}
```

---

In my case, I don't plan on this implementation ever being extended, so I will probably resolve it by making it `sealed`, but I admit I don't really understand why it matters if it is sealed or not.

Also, just because my class is sealed, FxCop no longer tells me that `Dispose()` should call `GC.SupressFinalize(this);` but is that really true? Is it "better" in .NET to just always call SupressFinalize in Dispose regardless?

Comment: Perhaps your interface shouldn't implement IDisposable if you have things that implement your interface that don't need disposing. You can implement IDisposable *in addition* to your interface as necessary.

Comment: @DBM OP is implementing another interface that inherits IDisposable.  `IEnumerator<T>` is an example.

Comment: @DBM: If most implementations are disposable, this interface should also be, to encourage users of the interface to dispose correctly.

Comment: I don't know what FxCop is doing, but i want to point out that your class is acutually missing the finalizer. So SuppressFinalize does nothing.

Comment: @DBM: If a factory is going return things that may or may not be `IDisposable`, the return type of the factory should be `IDisposable`.  This is the reason `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable`--it's the return type of a factory method.

Comment: Yeah, not that it really matters, but in my real application, the instance is dependency injected, and some implementations do need to dispose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SuppressFinalize()` is meaningless unless your instance has a finalizer.
If your class doesn't have a finalizer, but is not `sealed`, you should still `SuppressFinalize`, in case an inherited class adds a finalizer.

Both of your options are correct, except that `Dispose(bool)` needs to be `protected virtual`.

Comment: Actually, the second option is not correct because the `Dispose(bool)` overload is not overridable.  +1 for pointing out that `SuppressFinalize` is meaningless on objects with no finalizer.

Comment: Is there any case in which a class should add a cleanup finalizer to a base class which is not designed for one, and is there any reason such a class couldn't handle the GC.SuppressFinalize in its own Dispose method?  I understand that it can be useful for classes to have finalizers whose purpose is simply to log a failure to dispose, but attempting cleanup in a finalizer when the base class isn't designed for it seems dangerous and wrong.  Encapsulating an instance of a finalizable class would seem much safer.

Comment: @supercat: If the derived class adds unmanaged resources.  The derived class cannot override `Dispose()`.  (although I'm not sure why it can't call `SupressFinalize()` in `Dispose(true)`)

Comment: @SLaks: When should a derived class add unmanaged resources, though, as opposed to encapsulating those resources within a new class whose purpose is to manage them?  An instance of that new class would then be a managed resource, so there'd be no need to add unmanaged resources into the derived class.

Answer (score 2):

In your "implement part of the typical pattern" option, you should make your `Dispose(bool)` method `protected virtual`:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) 
{ 
}
```

That will provide subclasses an opportunity to handle disposal of any resources they manage.  That's the meaning of "overridable" in "Provide an overridable implementation of Dispose(bool)"

Of course, `public virtual` would also satisfy FxCop.

Comment: @rally25rs But FxCop did warn you about that, when it said "provide an overridable implementation of Dispose(bool)."  Did the warning disappear when you provided a non-overridable implementation of Dispose(bool)?  If so, that's just weird.

Comment: Yep, in my 2nd example there where Dispose() is private, there is no FxCop warning.